# How to middle align two inner divs inside a container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Note: The dashed line is just a guide showing that `.inner-a` and `.inner-b` are both horizontally and vertically middle aligned to an imaginary split of `.outer` down the middle.

Is this possible using just CSS? Or would it need some javascript to achieve?

Here is what I have till now:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-a"></div>
  <div class="inner-b"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.inner-a, inner-b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inner-a {
  float:left;
}
.inner-b {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Give us more information on that, maybe some HTML code and height of your inner elements.

Comment: @makshh Just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.outer { display: inline-flex; align-items: center; }
```

Comment: "flex containers" they are real handy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid red
}
.inner-a, .inner-b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
  border:2px solid #000;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-a"></div>
  <div class="inner-b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap 4 you can [use the flexbox utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) and avoid the extra CSS..

```
<div class="outer d-inline-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="inner-a">a</div>
      <div class="inner-b">b</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fA7OzCOQVp

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem! I didn't know that was built into BS4 already.